# Adding headers to my fetch request causes CORS failure (express)

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I'm using the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) library and have the following settings on my server (running on `localhost:8000`):

```js
  cors({
    // Allow requests from these origins :: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    origin: `http://localhost:8001`,

    // Allow certain headers :: Access-Control-Allow-Headers
    allowedHeaders: [
      "Origin",
      "X-Requested-With",
      "Content-Type",
      "Accept",
      "Authorization"
    ],

    // Allows us to send cookies cross origin :: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
    credentials: true,

    // Allow this method
    methods: "GET"
  });
```

This works fine when I make a request like this:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/test', { method: 'GET', credentials: 'include', mode: 'cors' })
```

But I get a CORS error in the console when I add headers to the request:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/test', { method: 'GET', credentials: 'include', mode: 'cors', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
```

The Error I'm getting in Chrome is:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/test' from origin 'http://localhost:8001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The only difference is that I added a `Content-Type` header, but I would expect this to work because its in my list of `allowedHeaders`

Comment: Your server doesn’t seem to be configured to handle the OPTIONS requests. Try adding `app.options('*', cors())` to your code. See the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: Cheers — glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

```
  origin: `http:localhost:3001`,
```

It seems wrong, back slashes (//) are missing. Otherwise your sample looks good and it works if I create a simple server with your sample.

If it still does not work, you can try to clear the cache. There was an issue in github: https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/159